# Database in SqlServer doesn't get Effected when using Database First Approach in Entity FrameWork in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I Used Database First Approach on entity framework it work fine.Database are stored in visual studio but it is not effecting the original database ko sql server 2008.i followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx.  for studying .Any help plz

Comment: What do you meant by `but it is not effecting the original database` ?

Comment: database of server is not being effected on any operation ,the database which is in program .mdf is being effect

Comment: Then your change your connection string to SQL server.

Comment: I'll add it as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then make sure your connection string is correct. [More details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx)